# How to fix this single quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want this code to be implemented...

```
var clone = $('<div><p>Email:'+email+'</p><div class="clear"></div>'+s+'<div class="clear"></div>Name: '+username+'</div>');
```

and my second string is this

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="usr_followbtn_3" onclick="user_follow('Tiger',this,'usr_unfollowbtn_3','You now follow Tiger.');" class="followusr" onfocus="this.blur();"><b>Follow</b></a>
```

and i want to be attach the second code to the first one something like this

```
var clone = $('<div><p>Email:'+email+'</p><div class="clear"></div>'+s+'<div class="clear"></div>Name: '+username+'<a href="javascript:;" id="usr_followbtn_2" onclick="user_follow(\'pranabksingh\\\'',this,'\usr_unfollowbtn_2\\\',\'You now follow pranabksingh\\\');" class="followusr" onfocus="this.blur();"><b>Follow</b></a></div>');
```

But it doesn't work... i think there's a problem with the single quotes...

Comment: yup you are messing with the quotes, proper nesting of codes is not done here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the link to the div element using this:

```
var link = $("<a href='javascript:;' id='usr_followbtn_3' onclick='user_follow(\"Tiger\",this,\"usr_unfollowbtn_3\",\"You now follow Tiger.\");' class='followusr' onfocus='this.blur();'><b>Follow</b></a>");

$('.clear').append(link);
```

But I believe better solution is to attach link's event listeners later or something link this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HNjtf/

And the string you want to construct should be something like that:

```
var clone = $('<div><p>Email:'+email+'</p><div class="clear"></div>'+s+'<div class="clear"></div>Name: '+username+'<a href="javascript:;" id="usr_followbtn_2" onclick="user_follow(\'pranabksingh\', this ,\'usr_unfollowbtn_2\',\'You now follow pranabksingh\');" class="followusr" onfocus="this.blur();"><b>Follow</b></a></div>');
```

Actually I'm not advising you to do something like the upper snipped.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but here's what i'm looking for...   var clone = $('<div><p>Email:'+email+'</p><div class="clear"></div>'+s+'<div class="clear"></div>Name: '+username+'<a href="javascript:;" id="usr_followbtn_2" onclick="user_follow(\'pranabsingh\\\'', this,'\usr_unfollowbtn_2\\\\', '\'You now follow pranabksingh\\\')">Follow</a></div>');